# How to store data table value in another data table with filter

Tags: c#, datatable, ado

How to store data table value in another data table with filter.

```
DataTabe dt = objProfitLossDT.Select("AppBalance <= 0");
```

Comment: Create a new DataTable and set the DataSource property to be your query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
DataTable dt = objProfitLossDT.Select("AppBalance <= 0").CopyToDataTable();
```

Note that [`CopyToDataTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatableextensions.copytodatatable?view=netframework-4.7.2) throws an exception if there is no row in source. So you should check it:

```
DataTable dt = objProfitLossDT.Clone(); // Clone is better than assigning null if you need the columns with an empty table
DataRow[] filteredRows = objProfitLossDT.Select("AppBalance <= 0");
if(filteredRows.Length > 0)
    dt = objProfitLossDT.Select("AppBalance <= 0").CopyToDataTable();
```

By the way, you know that you could also use LINQ, which is much more powerful than `Select`:

```
var filteredRows = objProfitLossDT.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => row.Field<int>("AppBalance) <= 0)
    .ToArray(); // if you want a DataRow[]
```